# Retrieving data in Rails both ways from 2 column join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `ChunkRelationship` model with a table that looks like this:

```
+----+---------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |      chunk_id |  chunk_partner | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |             1 |              2 | 2010-02-14 12:11:22 | 2010-02-14 12:11:22 | 
|  2 |             2 |              1 | 2010-02-14 12:11:22 | 2010-02-14 12:11:22 | 
+----+---------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Both entries are foreign keys to a `Chunk` model.  Right now, the relationship is being saved twice, once in both directions ( 2 => 1 and 1 => 2).  But the relationship can be saved once, because if one ID is known then the other can be found (What is this type of table called?).

I am wondering what the Rails way of doing that would be.  I was thinking of creating a `before_validation` callback on the `ChunkRelationship` model and taking the smallest number of the two and always saving that to the chunk_id column, which would allow for checking for duplicates easier before saving.  But from there I'm not sure how I would retrieve them.

The intended end result would be for `chunk.partners` to return all the rows paired with it, no matter which column either one is in.

Comment: Please share the schema of the tables and the models.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the `has_many_and_belongs_to` association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

This should create a many-to-many relationship which I believe you are describing.

Comment: I agree on this, but what about the unpopularity of this association? Many articles say to use a :through table over hmabt and that it is no longer needed.

Comment: Well, it would at least solve your situation. I don't know about the association itself in Rails, but the many-to-many join table pattern is commonly used in these types of situations.